# How to make career guidance system intelligent

Tags: java, algorithm, web, artificial-intelligence, drools

Well at-last I am working on my final year project which is *Intelligent web based career guidance system* the core functionality of my system is

## Recommendation System

Basically our recommendation system will carefully examine user preferences by taking Interest tests and user’s academic record and on the basis of this examined information it will give user the best career options i.e the course like BS Computer Science etc. .

- Input of the recommendation system will be the student credentials and Interest test and in interest test the questions will be given according to user academic history and the answers that he is giving in the test, so basically test will not be asking same questions from everyone it will decide on real time about what to ask from which user according to rules defined by the system.
- Its output will be the option of fields which will be decided on the basis of Interest test.

## Problem

When I was defending my scope infront of committee they said "this is simple *if-else*" this system is not intelligent.
My question is which AI technique or Algorithm could be use to make this system intelligent. I have searched a lot but papers related to my system are much more superficial they are just emphasizing on idea not on methodology.
I want to do all my work in Java. It is great if answer is technology specific.

 You people can transfer my question to any other stackexchange site if it is not related  to SO Q&A criteria.

### Edit

After getting some idea from answers I want to implement expert system with rule based and inference engine. Now I want to be more clear on technology aspect to implement rule based engine. After searching I have found Drools to be best but Is it also compatible with web applications?  And I also found Tohu to be best dynamic form generator (as this is also need of my project). can I use tohu with drools to make my web application? Is it easy to implement this type of system or not?

Comment: Making a system intelligent isn't just a matter of picking a technique, slapping it into the system, and turning it loose.  I think they are subtly telling you that you need to think about what AI brings to the application domain that an if-then-else system doesn't (or in other words, what can AI do for you that a simple database can't) before you go charging forward and picking techniques.

Comment: are you sure the committee is intelligent enough to understand if a system is not intelligent?

Comment: I don't quite understand - do you have rules already or is the problem that you need to find the rules? If you need to learn the rules - do you have data to learn from?

Comment: @kutschkem i already have rules. And  now i want to implement rule base engine with web compatibility in drools.

Comment: @james May i ask how you got the rules? I want to understand your project better.

Comment: @kutschkem my co-supervisor is a professional counselor. she gave us sample rules to implement. I  only need to give the proof of concept in front of committee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my final project, I had some experience with [Jena RDF](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdf/index.html) inference engine. Basically, what you do with it is create a sort of knowledge base with rules like "if user chose this answer, he has that quality" and "if user has those qualities, he might be good for that job". Adding answers into the system will let you query his current status and adjust questions accordingly. It's pretty easy to create a proof of concept with it, it's easier to do than a bunch of if-else, and if your professors worship prolog-ish style things, they'll like it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but what i am not getting is how it avoids the bunch of if-else statements? Like for knowledge base system i will have to write the number of if else statements..like you mentioned "if user has those qualities ,he might be good for that job"..Could you please elaborate more on it?

Comment: @james: what I mean is you create a set of rules, not just if-else statements. And using this set of rules the inference engine is doing something way more complicated than what you would've been able to do with if-elses.

Comment: What i need to learn if i want to start with inference engine?Or how to start with inference engine?

Comment: This way is good if your problem is similar to matching wine varietals with meals, where you have a body of knowledge and want to express it in a manner that allows the computer to deduce new information. http://www.ksl.stanford.edu/projects/wine/explanation.html

Answer (score 4):

1. If you have a large amount of question, each of them can represent a *feature*. Assuming you are going to have a LOT of features, **finding the series of if-else statements that fulfills the criteria is hard** (Recall that a full tree with `n` questions is going to have `2^n` "leaves" - representing `2^n` possible answers for these questions, assuming each question is yes/no question).
2. Since hard programming the above is not possible for a large enough (and probably a realistic size `n` - there is a place for *heuristical solutions* one of those is [Machine Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning), and specifically - the [**classification** problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification). You can have a sample of people answering your survey, with an "expert" saying what is the best career for them, and let an algorithm find a classifier for the general problem (If you want to convert it into a series of yes-no questions automatically, it can be done with a decision tree, and an algorithm like [C4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm) to create the tree).
3. It could also be important to determine - which questions are actually relevant? Is a gender relevant? Is height relevant? These questions as well can be answered using ML algorithms with [**feature selection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) algorithms for example (one of these is [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis))
4. Regarding the "technology" aspect - there is a nice library in java - called [**Weka**](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) which implement many of the classification algorithms out there.
5. One question you could ask (and try to find out in your project) **which classification algorithm will be best for this problem?** Some possibilities are The above mentioned C4.5, [Naive Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), [Linear Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), [Neural Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network), [KNN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) or [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) (which usually turned out best for me). You can try and back your decision which algorithm to use with a statistical research and a [statistical proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) which is better. [Wilcoxon test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) is the standard for this.

---

**EDIT:** more details on point 2:

- In here an "expert" can be a human classifier from the field of HR
  that reads the features and classifies the answers. Obtaining this
  data (usually called the "training data") is hard and expansive
  sometimes, if your university has an IE or HR faculty, maybe they
  will be willing to help.
- The idea is: Gather a bunch of people who first answer your survey. Then, give it to a human classifier ("expert") which will chose what is the best career for this person, based on his answers. The data with the classification given by the expert is the input of the learning algorithm, its output will be a classifier.
- A classifier is a function itself, that given answers to a surveys - predicts what is the "classification" (suggested career) for the person who did this survey.
- Note that once you have a classifier - you do not need to maintain the training data any more, the classifier alone is enough. However, you should have your list of questions and the answers for these questions will be the features provided to the classifier.

Comment: Well Thanks for your answer again..but could you please provide more detail regarding your 2nd point? like what is an expert? And how it suggests that what is best career for some body? and what is an input/output of this? And in this scenario whether i am not storing any question in database? then how it works?

Comment: Thanks again First of all your points are very much relevant and interesting  that's why i want to be more clear..In 2nd bullet  you are saying that "classifier is a  human expert" and then on the next line you mentioned that "the output of learning algorithm will be classifier" are they both classifier same?...Also you wrote that "once you have a classifier.." are you talking about human classifier here? Then how could i say that my system is intelligent? In this case the human is looking intelligent not system..

Comment: @james: The "expert" is a human classifier - telling you what is the classification. The learning algorithm will give you an algorithmic classifier (machine) based on the results of the expert. The idea is the algorithmic classifier (output of the learning algorithm) will try to be as similar as it can to the human classifier (expert) - this is eventually the goal of the learning algorithm. "once you have a classifier" refers to the algorithmic one, generated by the learning algorithm. You should read the links I attached about machine learning and statistical classifcation.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do to satisfy them is create a simple learning system:

1. Change your thesis terminology so it is described as "learning the best career" instead of using the word "intelligent". Learning is a form of artificial intelligence.
2. Create a training regime. Do this by giving the questionnaire to people that already have careers and also ask questions to find out how satisfied they are with their career. That way your system can train on what makes a good career match and what makes a bad one.
3. Choose a learning system to absorb the data from (2). For example, one source of ideas might be this recent paper: http://journals.cluteonline.com/index.php/RBIS/article/download/4405/4493. Product sum networks are cutting edge in AI and apply well to expert-system-like problems.

Finally, try to give a twist to whatever your technology is to make it specific to your problem.

Comment: thanks...the paper you have recommended me is about Rule-Based Expert Systems. i also want to go in this direction but i need your guidance on some technology aspects. Like my project is web app so it will be fine if i go with Drools? Or combination of drools and tohu(for dynamic form generation)? It will be great if you guide me regarding drools and also keep in mind that the application is web based.

Comment: Drools is fine. If you are more ambitious you could try to implement a product-sum network, as I mentioned, a very cutting edge technology. Here is a seminal paper on that: http://turing.cs.washington.edu/papers/uai11-poon.pdf. If this is about AI I would minimize the web stuff, its just a time-consuming distraction. You don't want to waste a lot of time making web pages if the goal is intelligent learning.

Comment: I agree with the idea of de-emphasizing the web component. The means of eliciting feedback in a manner that improves response rate and the value of the responses is an interesting problem, but should be left for later. If you don't know what a good career choice is and want your software to "discover" it from the data this answer is a good choice. If you think you already have useful rules for what careers match skills or educations the RDF based answer would be worth investigating. That way does not require a training, as it merely represents/applies existing knowledge to deduce the results.

Comment: @TylerDurden well to make the system web based is one of my core requirement because people can only access my product through web. I  want to know if the system is web based then Drools is compatible with it? Or can i build a web based system in which all the rules are written in drools?

Answer (score 1):

A program is never more intelligent than the person who wrote it. So, I would first use the collective intelligence that has been built and open sourced already.

Pass your set of known data points as an input to Apache Mahout's [PearsonCorrelationSimilarity](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/similarity/PearsonCorrelationSimilarity.html) and use the output to predict which course is the best match. In addition to being open source and scalable, you can also record the outcome and feed it back to the system to improve the accuracy over time. It is very hard to match this level of performance because it is a lot easier to tweak an out of the box algorithm or replace it with your own than it is to deal with a bunch of if else conditions.

I would suggest reading this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182684) . It contains an example of how to use PearsonCorrelationSimilarity.

Mahout also has built in recommender algorithms like [NearestNeighborClusterSimilarity](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/recommender/NearestNeighborClusterSimilarity.html) 
that can simplify your solution further.

There's a good starter code in the book. You can build on it.

Student credentials, Interest Test Questions and answers are inputs. Career choice is the output that you can co-relate to the input. Now that's a very simplistic approach but it might be ok to start with. Eventually, you will have to apply the classifier techniques that Amit has suggested and Mahout can help you with that as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but could you please elaborate your point and tell how the system will predict using PearsonCorrelationSimilarity about the user career?

Comment: Well i go through the book you have recommended. This book is nice but more about the recommendation system which Amazon youtube or google are using. Could you please tell me how it relate to the concept of my "career guidance recommendation system"? And what do you mean by "set of known data points" In 3rd line?..Your assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As @amit suggested, Bayesian analysis can provide you guidance on the next question to ask. Another pitfall of dynamic tests is artificial thresholds ("if your score is 28, you are in this category, if your score is 27, you are not"), a problem which fuzzy logic can help address. Another benefit of fuzzy logic is that adding a new category is relatively easy, since the domain expert is only asked to contribute qualitative assessments, not quantitative thresholds.

Answer (score 1):

Drools can be used via the web, but watch out; it can be a bit of beast to configure and is likely serious overkill for your application.  It is an 'enterprise' type of solution focused around rule management, rather than rule execution.

Drools is an "IF-THEN" system, and pretty much all rules engines use the Rete algorithm.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm - so if your original question is about how not to use an IF-THEN system, Drools is not the right choice.  Now, there is a Solver and Planner part of Drools that are not IF-THEN algorithms, but this is not the main Drools algorithm.

That said, it seems like a reasonable choice for your application.  Just don't expect it to be considered an 'intelligent' system by those who deem themselves as experts.  Rules engines are typically used to codify (that is, make software of) the rules and regulations of business, such as 'should you be approved for a mortgage' or 'how much is your car insurance' and so on.  'what job you should do' is a reasonable application of the same.

If you want to add more AI like intelligence here are a few ideas

- Use machine learning to get feedback from the user about earlier recommendations.  So, if someone likes or hates a suggestion, add that back in as a feature of the person.  You are now doing some basic feedback/reinforcement learning (bayes, neural nets) to try to better classify the person to the career.
- Consider the questions you ask the person.  Do you need to ask all of the questions?  If you can alter the flow of questions based on their responses (by estimating what kind of person they are) then you are trying to learn the series of questions that gives the most useful knowledge for a recommendation.

If you want specific software, look at Weka http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/ - it has many great algorithms for classifying.  And it is a Java library, so you can easily use it within a web application.

Good luck.

Comment: And if you want an easy to use Java based web framework, look at playframework.org v1.x (I would not recommend 2.x for your application).

Comment: +1 Thanks..please clarify one more thing i.e All the tools cane be used under the umbrella of your recommended framework? Like if i use drools(for rule management)+Weka(to apply some classification algorithm). what i'm not sure is Drools is a project of JBoss and using drools under any other framework would be allowed or not? Just clarify how different technologies can be used in one project or can i use different technologies like this?

Comment: drools is a huge project - you can use it in many contexts.  i suggest you just include the drools expert and call it directly.  here is a tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/jboss-drools-getting-started.html  

you can then call classes on your server to run the rules engine based on the form values the user enters.

Comment: i still think drools is overkill for your project though.  there are simpler rules engines out there.  as i said, drools is for enterprise apps where a big issue is maintaining the rule base (updating by non-coders, etc).

Comment: Simpler rule engine? can you provide me example pls?

Comment: take your pick: http://java-source.net/open-source/rule-engines  - however, it's not terribly complicated to use the drools expert jar via your code either, but you'll have to spend some time figuring that out.